# Winium.desktop - Handle new desktop window

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I'm automating a desktop task for my company using Winium.Desktop. The first step is to do a login and it does so opening a new window. The next step is to fullfil a form and sometimes the new window is not focused. So the automation continues on the window that is currently focused (old window from the automation).
Searching around the web i found this:

```
1: String parentHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
2: for (String handle: driver.getWindowHandles()) {
3:    if (!parentHandle.equals(handle))
4:       driver.switchTo().window(handle);
5: }
```

Got an exception:
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String
on line 2

Not sure if I can use it but this code above was used for a browser window and that's not my case.

How can I focus on the new program window?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch window then you can match condition...See the sample code

```
//wait for few seconds for loading site
    for (String windows : driver.getWindowHandles()) {

                driver.switchTo().window(windows);

                if (driver.getCurrentUrl().startsWith("xyz.com")) {

                //Your Operation
                   }
                if (driver.getCurrentUrl().startsWith("yzx.com")) {
    //Your Operation
                    }


            }
```

> Hope it will solve your problem

Comment: Its a desktop program that the user login into. Its not a web browser.

Comment: oww I think concept will be like same

Answer (score 0):

So I came up with a temporary solution.

```
public static final <T> T nthElement(Iterable<T> data, int n){
    int index = 0;
    for(T element : data){
        if(index == n){
            return element;
        }
        index++;
    }
    return null;
}

public static void focusNewWindow() {
    Object count = nthElement(driver.getWindowHandles(), 0);
    driver.switchTo().window(count.toString());
}
```

Everytime I call this window in the automation it becomes the first element in a window list (internal). So I made a function to return an element based on the index and passed 0 to the second param.

It's temporary because it works if you run the automation with no other windows opened.